# Magento2: Insert brand name above product name in product page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.1, product-detail-page

I would like to insert brand name above product name in product page in a Magento 2.2.1. I managed to do it with regards to product list. I modified file `list.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/../../Magento_Catalog/templates/product`.

However, I don't know how to display it on product page. Can you help me? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: is it Attribute (brand) ?

Comment: Yes, manufacture

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code in list.phtml. You can display Brand anywhere in Product detail page.

```
  $_attributeValues = $block->getProduct()->getResource()
                              ->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()
                              ->getValue($block->getProduct());
```